# Remove for systematic error (ANOVA)

Tags: anova, error

Having a systematic 'error' (due to a 3 leveled external/experimental factor) influencing the variable I want to predict with my model.
How do I best find a sound model that represents the underlying relation of interest, not fitting these 'errors'?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  Could you restate it or elaborate it?

Comment: Understandable! I can barely understand it myself. It was late. Anyway there is some extra meat in the comment I wrote below. Might still not make sense though. Also the question is quite impractical/unpragmatic.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like what you want to do is incorporate the external experimental factor as a blocking variable. It's included in the model like any other term, but you typically don't do hypothesis tests involving it. Ideally, your blocking variable is known before hand and you design your experiment taking it into account; since this is *post hoc,* the blocking variable may end up being confounded with variables of interest, partially or completely. If it's completely confounded there's not much you can do with it; if it's only partially confounded there's still hope.

(If the order the experiments were conducted in was randomized, you should hopefully not end up with complete confounding.)

I don't know what program you're using for analysis, but most modern statistical analysis programs should involve an option to include blocking variables.

Comment: okay, thanks for answer! It's included as a block variable I guess but it's almost completely confounded w. another factor (no randomization) but not on a small subset of the data in which the 'another factor's influence is 0. What's left to influence response is two factors, the 'blocking' and another. 5 and 4 levels respectively. That's where the systematic differences shows. So I guess the right answer would be to make a new experiment. But If this data was homo sapiens last hope in face of potential extinction..

Comment: Or we could just delete this question since it's not really going to lead anywhere productive.